# Rails: saving nested attributes inside a transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, transactions, nested-attributes

I have a user model that accepts nested attributes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :skills
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :skills
end
```

In my controller I'm updating a user inside of a transaction:

```
def update
  @user = current_user
  @profile = current_profile

  begin
    User.transaction do
      @user.update_attributes!(user_params)
      @profile.update_attributes!(profile_params)
    end

    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  rescue
    render :edit
  end
end
```

When the user update succeeds but the profile update fails (i.e. validation error, etc.) the edit template is rendered with the nested skills.  Oddly though the nested skills attributes have IDs so that when I resubmit the edit form I get:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
Couldn't find Skill with ID=123 for User with ID=456
```

I believe what is happening here is that since the user update succeeds the nested skills are created.  The profile update fails and the whole transaction is rolled back (including the skills).  I would have expected that when the form is re-rendered the IDs for newly created skills should be blank.

Is this a bug?  Is there a better approach here?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it just the form rendered with the skills or did they actually got saved to the database?

Comment: They get saved to the database during the call to `@user.update_attributes!`.

Comment: How can that be? When `@profile.update_attributes!` fails it raises an exception, right? At this point Rails rolls back the transaction and all database changes in the transaction block are rolled back. Check the log for a ROLLBACK SQL command.

Comment: Yes, the skills get rolled back and removed from the database but the skill IDs (now non-existent) persist when the form is re-rendered.

Comment: I think this is because the Ruby object itself doesn't get cleared when the validation fails. This is usually good since it gives the user a chance to edit the fields and re-submit the form. In your case you have to manually clear these fields when an exception is raised (I believe rails does that for password fields automatically)